AuthMiddleware is DEPRECATION and public routes are not working in clerkMiddleware
I was watching a tutorial he use authMiddleware and public routes but I am not happing to find alternative of new public routes in clerkMiddleware as
Here's my code with authMiddleware:
import { authMiddleware } from '@clerk/nextjs/server'

export default authMiddleware({
  publicRoutes: ['/site', '/api/uploadthing'],})

  export const config = {
    matcher: ['/((?!.+\\.[\\w]+$|_next).*)', '/', '/(api|trpc)(.*)'],
  }

Here's what I tried to do and it told that No overload matches this call in the public routes line:
import { clerkMiddleware } from '@clerk/nextjs/server'

export default clerkMiddleware({ publicRoutes: ['/site', '/api/uploadthing'],})

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/((?!.+\\.[\\w]+$|_next).*)', '/', '/(api|trpc)(.*)'],
  
}


Please tell what I need to use instead of public route?
